# How to read the query string in PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html, query-string

a URL ending with something like `portal.php?key2=hello` how can I get the value of "key2"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var_dump( $_GET['key2'] );
```

Comment: var_dump displays the variable. You can always consult php manual (http://php.net) to know usage of a function.

Comment: var_dump is like a more informative version of echo used solely for debugging. So even if it was blank it would display something.

Answer (score 17):

```
$_GET['key2']
```

will get you the value from a query string.

```
$_POST['key2']
```

will get you the value from a form posted.

```
$_REQUEST['key2']
```

will get you either of the above if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

GET data is decoded into the $_GET super-global array. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php