# A list of <a> with an onclick event that sets a session variable. why does each event run?

Tags: php, html, anchor

I know this is usually done with AJAX and JS but I can't find out why this isn't working.
I need to set a session variable when the link is clicked that is retrieved on the next page to query a database and retrieve the correct type of product.

This is the code:

```
<li> <a onclick="<?php $_SESSION['table'] = 'knives'; ?>" href="shop-page.php">Knives</a></li>
<li> <a onclick="<?php $_SESSION['table'] = 'jewlery'; ?>" href="shop-page.php">Jewellery</a></li>
<li> <a onclick="<?php $_SESSION['table'] = 'lighting'; ?>" href="shop-page.php">Lighting</a></li>
<li> <a onclick="<?php $_SESSION['table'] = 'cookware'; ?>" href="shop-page.php">Cookware</a></li>
<li> <a onclick="<?php $_SESSION['table'] = 'architectural'; ?>" href="shop-page.php">Architectural</a></li>
<li> <a onclick="<?php $_SESSION['table'] = 'misc'; ?>" href="shop-page.php" >Misc.</a></li>
```

Whatever link is clicked each `onclick` runs and the session variable becomes `misc`.
Any help would be great and if this is just something that PHP can't do this way can someone point me toward a decent tutorial?
Many thanks

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854754/how-to-set-a-session-variable-when-clicking-a-a-link

Comment: @DenizEng I've been there already thanks, I tried the hyper link style buttons but refreshing breaks it as it doesnt post anything and i know i can save the post value in session but i mainly want to know why this doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work because you're trying to respond to a JS event with native code inside a JS event handler. So what ends up happening is, your php code runs(before any click as soon as you navigate to page containing code above) and session is always set to misc which is the last entry as the code is running in sequence. Instead, you need to either modify the urls and add the value that you want to pass as a parameter or post to your php page. This sample may help: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Sample for using a http get request(navigating to links on click) to pass values to php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153218/how-to-read-the-query-string-in-php-and-html.